# How can I get final bin size with javascript growing bin packing algorithm?

Tags: javascript, binary-tree, bin-packing

Using this [2d bin-packing algorithm](http://pastebin.com/Ke8WpMZ7) (EDIT: Fixed demo) which is a variation of [this](https://github.com/jakesgordon/bin-packing) how can I get the final bin width and height of each bin?

My demo code follows:

```
 var blocks = [
    {w: 1000, h: 800},
    {w: 500, h: 700},
    {w: 500, h: 700},
    {w: 500, h: 350},
    {w: 500, h: 350},
    {w: 500, h: 350},
    {w: 500, h: 350},
    {w: 500, h: 350},
    {w: 500, h: 350},
    {w: 500, h: 350},
    {w: 500, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350},
    {w: 250, h: 350}
];

var sheets = [];

while(blocks.length) {
    var packer = new GrowingPacker(1000,800);
    packer.fit(blocks);

    sheet = [];
    for (var i=blocks.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (blocks[i].fit !== undefined && blocks[i].fit !== null) {
            //console.log(blocks[i].fit);
            sheet.unshift(blocks[i]);
            blocks.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    //console.log(sheet[sheet.length-1].fit.y + sheet[sheet.length-1].h);
    //console.log(sheet);
    sheets.push(sheet);
}


for(var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var sheetWidth = sheet[sheet.length-1].w + sheet[sheet.length-1].fit.x;
    var sheetHeight = sheet[sheet.length-1].h + sheet[sheet.length-1].fit.y;

    for(var j=0; j<sheet.length; j++) {
        console.log("SHEET #" + i + " - W: " + sheetWidth + " H: " + sheetHeight + " BLOCK #" + j + " - W: " + sheet[j].w + " H: " + sheet[j].h + " X: " + sheet[j].fit.x + " Y: " + sheet[j].fit.y);
    }
}
```

The original algorithm only deals with a single, ever-expanding bin so I modified it to take a max width and height. Then I run through the array of blocks, call the packer, push fit blocks to a new array and unset them from 'blocks' until 'blocks' is empty. Whether that was the best approach is the subject of another question.

Anyway, I've tried modifying growNode like so:

```
growNode: function(w, h) {
    var canGrowRight  = (w <= this.root.w && this.root.w + w <= maxW);
    var canGrowDown = (h <= this.root.h && this.root.h + h <= maxH);

    if (canGrowRight) {
        this.sheetW = this.root.w + w; //<--------------added
        return this.growRight(w, h);
    }
    else if (canGrowDown) {
        this.sheetH = this.root.h + h; //<--------------added
        return this.growDown(w, h);
    }
    else

        return null; // need to ensure sensible root starting size to avoid this happening
},
```

which works for every sheet but the first one. I tried to add these lines in a few other methods as well with no success. I also tried to get the sheet size from the last block in the sheet's width + x but that only works if the sheet is full.

My question again is how can I get the final sheet size for each sheet?

Comment: Possibly. I didn't write the original tree algorithm I'm just mangling it to suit my purposes. An explanation of the original can be found here: http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing/

Comment: If you have more bins you need to loop through each bin and each bin needs a binary-tree. It's not working when you fill the first bin and then the second, third ....but you know it?

Comment: I don't know how many bins I'll need, it depends on how many blocks I have and how big they are. I loop through the blocks and pack them to a bin until it is full, then I unset them from the blocks array until blocks is empty. I know what the max bin size is but I'm trying to get the final bin size for each bin including bin's that are not full and haven't expanded to their max size.

Comment: But you wouldn't get the best packing with your approach. Anyway why do you need the max size of a bin? The goal is to pack as many blocks to fewest bin? Or do we misunderstand?

Comment: It's a special case. In this case bin packing is packing pictures to a sheet of paper. I can print to a max of 8x10. If I want to print two 5x7 I can pack them into a 7x10 sheet but then I dont want to print the last 1 inch. Or I can fit two 3.5x5 in a 3.5x10 or a half-sheet in which case I don't want to print a full 8x10, just 3.5x10. Sorry if it doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. I added two lines to findNode()

```
findNode: function(root, w, h) {
    if (root.used) {
        return this.findNode(root.right, w, h) || this.findNode(root.down, w, h);
    }
    else if ((w <= root.w && w <= this.maxW) && (h <= root.h && w <= this.maxW)) {
        this.binWidth = this.root.w <= this.maxW ? this.root.w : this.maxW;
        this.binHeight = this.root.h <= this.maxH ? this.root.h : this.maxH;
        return root;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
},
```

[Here is the jsfiddle if you want to play with it.](http://jsfiddle.net/XDGHE/3/) I recommend trying something like this for the input:

```
100x80
50x70
50x35x2
25x35x4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a growing algorithm and you can grow the bin to the left or to the right: http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2011/5/7/bin_packing.

Comment: This is where I got the algorithm in the first place. I linked to it in my question.